# SSRS connection to Informix

Tags: reporting-services, informix

I have an SSRS report connecting to an Informix db. The connection is ODBC. The report runs fine. My issue is when I try to update the report. Specifically when refreshing the sql for a dataset. I am using Report Builder. The specific steps, right click on the dataset, select properties, the query window displays and I click "refresh fields".
I get the following error "ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified"

I don't understand this error as the report runs fine using the Informix ODBC driver. I am not changing the sql. The user and password are correct.

Why does the report connect and run but this refresh does not ? Is the refresh somehow configured to use
a different data source ? I have never seen that

Any assistance is greatly appreciated. ( i also tried changing the data source to OLE and same problem with a different error)

Comment: Are you running an older 32bit version of ReportBuilder?  If so it would require 32bit ODBC drivers.  And of course the ODBC driver must be installed on the computer running ReportBuilder.

Comment: David,  thank you. I can't use the 32bit ODBC because then the report will not connect/run. The report runs but the refresh sql does not. When this report was created everything was 32 bit. Then I have to move to a 64 bit ODBC data source. So to your point I probably need to update the report builder to 64 bit and all should be good. I hope